# Как из готовой таблицы html удалить только текст из строки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
function colCount() {
    const cols = $('tr:first-child').find('td').length; //считаем количество колонок
    var m = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= cols; i++) { //в цикле по колонкам
        let count = 0; //создаем счётчик
        $('td:nth-child('+i+')').each(function(){ //в цикле по ячейкам каждой колонки
            if($(this).text() != '') { //проверяем, не пустая ли она
                count++; //увеличиваем счётчик
            }
        });
        m.push(count);
    }
    $('tr:eq(2)').find('th').each(function (i, el) {
        if (i < m.length)
            $(el).append( m[i] );
    });
}
```

Добавляю данные из массива в строку уже готовой html таблицы. При запуске этой функции второй раз. Данные добавляются повторно, но те которые добавились в первый раз остаются, а надо их удалить перед вторым добавлением.

Ситуация осложняется тем, что в этой строке присутствуют ещё и другие данные, сформированные другой функцией. Как мне удалить только те данные, которые добавляются из массива только этой функцией?

```
$('tr:eq(2)').find('th').each(function (i, el) {
            if (i < m.length)
                $(el).remove();
        });
```

Удаляет все данные вообще.

Comment: При добавлении записей в первый раз - помечайте их, ставьте им например класс class='to_remove', и при каждом добавлении удаляйте записи с этим классом

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.